# Is the spectrum of a signal circularly symmetric if the signal itself is circularly symmetric?

Tags: covariance, gaussian-process, posterior, frequency

Let’s consider a signal that is circularly symmetric complex Gaussian process (proper):

$$ s \sim \mathcal{CGP}(0, C, 0) $$, and,

the covariance has the following form:

$$ \mathbf{C} = \mathbf{C}_{rr} + \mathbf{C}_{ii} + j( \mathbf{C}_{ir} - \mathbf{C}_{ri} ) $$

where $\mathbf{C}_{rr} =  \mathbf{C}_{ii}$, and $\mathbf{C}_{ir} = - \mathbf{C}_{ri}$. Here, $_r$ refers to real part and $_i$ refers to imaginary, and $j=\sqrt{-1}$.

I have seen in literature that the posterior outputs and the observations are jointly proper. However, does it hold true also in the frequency domain?

What is the nature of the process in frequency domain? Is it also a proper complex Gaussian process?